# Passing QString from parent to child QT

Tags: c++, qt, class, variables, qstring

I need in my program to get one QString from parent window to child window.

```
 menu=new user(this);  menu->show();
```

This is how I am creating child window. I have `QString Username;` declared in my parent called "login".

This is how I am trying to pass QString to my new window:

```
 QString loginnn=((login*)this->parent())->Username
```

But I'm getting error:

> "login was not declared in this scope"

Although I've included "login.h" file to my "user.h" file, and also "login" is marked in pink colour, and QT know what it is.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you using an object name as a type name in:
   `((login*)this->parent())->Username`

Comment: Which is the parent class and which one is the child ? Can't you just pass `QString &` or `QString const &` in the constructor of the child, while creating it ?

Comment: `((login*)this->parent())->Username` - ever heard about encapsulation?

Comment: I think you have to see some intermediate c++ tutorials. you can see this channel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KtOzh0StTc&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to send a reference to the required string during your object construction

You should simply do this :

```
menu = new user(this, username);
menu->show();
```

**Menu.cpp**

```
class User
{
private:
     QString &_login;
public:
     User(..., QString &login):
       _login(login)
}
```

Now you should be able to use this string, which anyway would make sense to give during construction

Comment: Thank you very much for help!

Comment: If this answer fixed your issue, set this as the accepted answer